# django nesting TextField within ArrayField for postgres

Tags: python-3.x, django

Django provides a nice to way to write ArrayFields in PGSql:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield

eg:

```
class Board(models.Model):
    pieces = ArrayField(ArrayField(models.IntegerField()))
```

I also see other examples using CharField - which I have used in the past and works just fine.

Now, I was wondering if I can do the same with TextField like so:

```
class Board(models.Model):
    extra_array = ArrayField(models.TextField(blank=True), default=list)
```

Is this legit to do this? Are there any gotachas I need to be aware of? None of the examples seem to use TextField and I wondered why!

Comment: Did you **try**? The documentation states _"Most field types are permitted, with the exception of those handling relational data"_. You say _"None of the examples seem to use TextField"_. There's simply too many fields and add an example for each one would be redundant...

Comment: Ah! I just saw the `Most field types are permitted, with the exception of those handling relational data` :( being blind this morning - my apologies. Please post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly the documentation (as you link in your question) states:

> Most field types are permitted, with the exception of those handling
> relational data (**ForeignKey**, **OneToOneField** and
> **ManyToManyField**).

Considering this one should be quite sure a `TextField` would work. Looking into the code [this](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d01709aae21de9cd2565b9c52f32732ea28a2d98/django/contrib/postgres/fields/array.py#L53) is where an `ArrayField` checks if it is valid:

> ```
> def check(self, **kwargs):
>     errors = super().check(**kwargs)
>     if self.base_field.remote_field:
>         errors.append(
>             checks.Error(
>                 'Base field for array cannot be a related field.',
>                 obj=self,
>                 id='postgres.E002'
>             )
>         )
>     else:
>         # Remove the field name checks as they are not needed here.
>         base_errors = self.base_field.check()
> ```

This code does not suggest in anyway that a `TextField` is not a valid `base_field` (`TextField` does not set `remote_field` and as long as the field's own declaration is fine the else part would also work properly).

> **Note**: When not sure try! A question is *"Is it legit / possible to do XYZ?"* Is not a very good question. At most you would fail and find
> out XYZ does not work.